# Vim doesn't modify my colorschemes which i set on my .vimrc upon starting

Tags: vim, xterm

The colorschemes i set on my .vimrc don't get loaded everytime i start VIM. Once i'm in VIM, typing ***:colo colorschemename*** the color scheme loads perfectly. Why does the colorscheme don't get loaded upon starting VIM.

I have enabled 256 colors in my xterm.
and i have CSApprox Plugin

```
echo $TERM //report xterm-256terminal
tput colors//256
```

ON VIM: entering this command

```
set t_Co? //256
```

Another thing is loading the **preinstalled** colorschemes in VIM works perfectly. **E.g** (evening, desert,.etc)

It works perfectly before.
The things that i did before it went wrong.
Sorry i'm a newbie in Linux.

1. I've changed .Xdefaults to .Xresources with the same contents

> *customization: -color
>
> XTerm*termName: xterm-256color

1. I accidentally cleared xrdb by typing xrdb then pressing CTRL-D. Is that bad if i cleared xrdb? What i did after that is execute:

> xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xresources

Btw, on Gvim the colorscheme loads correctly.
I'm Using Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Here's what my .vimrc under $HOME/.vimrc

```
"**********************************************"
"           VUNDLE SETTINGS                    "
"**********************************************"

set nocompatible " be iMproved 
filetype off    " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
filetype plugin indent on " required!

"**********************************************"
"           PLUGINS                            "
"**********************************************"
"EasyMotion
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
"Sparkup
Bundle 'tristen/vim-sparkup'
"Surround
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
"CsApprox
Bundle 'godlygeek/csapprox'

"**********************************************"
"           COLOR SCHEMES                      "
"**********************************************"

"   Distinguised
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-distinguished'
"   Github  
Bundle 'endel/vim-github-colorscheme'
"   VividChalk  
Bundle 'tpope/vim-vividchalk'
"   Pyte    
Bundle 'therubymug/vim-pyte'
"   Vibrantink
Bundle 'vim-scripts/vibrantink'

"**********************************************"
"           MAP LEADER                         "
"**********************************************"
let mapleader = ","

"**********************************************"
"           SYNTAX                             "
"**********************************************"
syntax enable

"**********************************************"
"           VIM SCRIPTS                        "
"**********************************************"
if has('gui_running') 
    colorscheme github
else 
    colorscheme pyte
endif

"**********************************************"
"           CUSTOM SETTINGS                    "
"                                              "
"**********************************************"
set hidden

" Show what mode you're currently at
set showmode

" Enable enhanced command line completion
set wildmenu

" Don't redraw while executing macros
set lazyredraw

" Indentation settings (SOFT TABS)"
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set smarttab
set expandtab "enable this to use spaces instead of tabs

" show line number
set nu

" hightlight as you type
set incsearch
" ignore case when searching
set ignorecase

" set statusline
set laststatus=2

"**********************************************"
"       NOTE don't map <c-s> and <c-q>         "
"**********************************************"

"**********************************************"
"           KEYMAPS                            "
"**********************************************"

"*******NORMAL MODE MAPPING********"
"map for editing .vimrc
nnoremap <leader>ev :e $MYVIMRC<cr>
"map for sourcing vimrc
nnoremap <leader>sv :so $MYVIMRC<cr>
"map for switching windows
"_ in this keymap is to jump for a line with a nonblank char
nnoremap <space> <c-w><c-w>_

"*******INSERT MODE Mapping********"
"map for escape while in insert mode
inoremap <leader>; <esc>
"map for ins-completion
inoremap <leader>x <c-x>

"*********COMMAND MODE Mappings*******
"exit out of command line mode
cnoremap <leader>; <c-c>
```

**Edit**

It seems like the colorsheme is indeed loaded. Upon first loading, Typing *:colorscheme* reports the correct colorscheme which i set on my .vimrc. 
 But it doesn't take effect the first time.
  I have to either type on VIM

`:colo 'colorschemename'*`

or source it again to activate the colorscheme using

```
:so $MYVIMRC
```

But after exiting VIM, the colorscheme again doesn't take effect but it is loaded upon starting VIM.

I've executed this on the terminal:

```
/usr/share/terminfo/d/darwin-256x96
/usr/share/terminfo/d/darwin-256x96-m
/usr/share/terminfo/E/Eterm-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/p/putty-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/k/konsole-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color-s
/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color-bce-s
/usr/share/terminfo/g/gnome-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/v/vte-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/x/xnuppc+256x96
/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+256color
/usr/share/terminfo/x/xnuppc-256x96-m
/usr/share/terminfo/x/xnuppc-256x96
/usr/share/terminfo/m/mrxvt-256color
/usr/share/terminfo/m/mlterm-256color
```

**NOTE**: I've installed ncurses-term.
Is it correct that the xterm is *xterm+256color* instead of *xterm-256color*

Btw. I've already edited my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more detail, like excerpts from your `.vimrc` or/and `.gvimrc`.

Comment: Where did you put your colorschemes?

Comment: @Kevin Sjoberg, I've edited the question.
I have no .gvimrc on my home directory.

Comment: @romainl I've put my colorschemes on my $HOME directory

Comment: Need to place it in `$VIM/colors` (or was it `$VIM/plugins/colors`? I forget) where `$VIM` could be `~/.vim` depending on your setup.

Comment: @john2x, I've used vundle to install colorschemes.

it's located under .vim/bundle/

Comment: should i set .xsession even though i have .Xresources?
Does .Xresource get's loaded upon login?

Comment: .Xresources should not come into play here. Your $TERM is correctly set and gvim colors look fine, so this doesn't seem X-related.

Comment: Have you try to see if it works in Gnome-Terminal? If it's also not working in Gnome-Terminal try to move `colorscheme pyte` out of gui_running if statement.

Comment: @number5, it doesn't work as well in gnome-terminal.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, thanks so its safe to remove .Xresources here?

i accidentally cleared my xrdb. does that mean something bad?
then i just reread .Xresources using xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xresources

Comment: `filetype plugin indent on` should come *after* all your `Bundle foo`. Also, try installing your colorscheme normally, in `~/.vim/colors/`.

Comment: thanks to all the replies guys. I've already found the solution. :)
I've posted the answer below

Comment: @chanHXC I don't mean to remove it - you may have other necessary xterm settings in there, just that it should not have an impact on Vim's colorscheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. I think i have to answer my own question. I'm really on despair so i went on to removing the plugins one by one through **BundleClean!** in **Vundle** to check if there's any plugin misbehaving.

It was not a problem with my .vimrc after all. It was a conflict with
**EasyMotion** and **CSApprox** plugins.

I had my **EasyMotion** configuration before **CSApprox** on **Vundle**
I followed the instructions on this one.

https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion/issues/55

Here's another one that might help others with the same issues as mine.

https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion/issues/39

Comment: You should put the instruction into this answer so that people don't have to follow the link if they don't want to.